# AddRowEvent in DataGridView Adding Extra Row

Tags: .net, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I have an unbounded DataGridView. I am trying to eliminate the extra row being added at the end. I have set the AllowUserToAddRows to false.

```
// This code is adding two rows at the beginning
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
dataGridView1.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
dataGridView1.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(false);
```

I have it setup when the user right clicks on a row, they will be able to add an extra row. However, if I right click on the last row, it will add two rows.

```
private void addRowBelowToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_selectedRow < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(_selectedRow + 1, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    }
    dataGridView1.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    dataGridView1.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In DataGridView is an event called "NewRowNeeded". So if newrowneeded is called just set

```
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
```

and add some Rows with:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

hope this will help you! see you!